# How to exclude bundling of osenv in angular-cli with electronjs

Tags: angular5

`angular-cli` is bundling `osenv node_modules` since the `service ts` file is being referenced inside `app.component.ts` which makes sense. Is there a way I can exclude those node_modules which are file system `electronjs` specific? Below is the stacktrace

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/osenv/osenv.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 
'C:\POC\Electron\fileexplorer\node_modules\osenv'
resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\POC\Electron\fileexplorer\node_modules\osenv'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: 
C:\POC\Electron\fileexplorer\node_modules\osenv\package.json (relative path: .)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find fix for this issue however I had to use webpack configuration instead of angular-cli below are the steps

- 1) run ng eject
- 2) edit webpack.config.js and add "child_process":
  'empty' to

  "node": {
     "fs": "empty",
     "global": true,
  "crypto": "empty",
  "tls": "empty",
  "net": "empty",
  "process": true,
  "module": false,
  "clearImmediate": false,
  "setImmediate": false,
  **"child_process": 'empty'**
  },
- 3) npm run build